# Javascript Memory Savings - if Statement var Declarations

Tags: javascript, variables, memory, if-statement

Do variables get initialized / stored in memory if they reside in an if statement which doesn't execute, as in the following:

```
function blah(){
    if(something === true){
        var blahOne = 1;
        var blahTwo = 2;
        var blahThree = 3;
    } else {
        console.log('The above if statement usually won\'t execute');
    }
}
```

My assumption is no, but Javascript can be a quirky language to say the least. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All `var` declarations are moved to the top of the function and initialized to undefined. That is called variable hoisting. JavaScript doesn't have block scope, only function and global scope.

Your code is equivalent to the following

```
function blah(){
    var blahOne, blahTwo, blahTree;
    if(something === true){
        blahOne = 1;
        blahTwo = 2;
        blahThree = 3;
    } else {
        // blahOne, blahTwo, blahThree are set to undefined
        console.log('The above if statement usually won\'t execute');
        // But since they have been declared, there's no error in reading them
        console.log(blahOne, blahTwo, blahThree);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no thing like a `block scope` in Javascript. See this [article](http://www.2ality.com/2013/05/quirk-variable-scope.html). if you want to say so: Javascript has function-scope. So the answer to your question is `yes` they get initialized.

Comment: They get initialized, but not to `1,2,3`, it's better to say they get declared but not initialized, since their values will be undefined if `something !== true`

Comment: I didn't say that. I only said: they get initialized and have to be garbage collected.

Comment: ^ I'm familiar with the general idea of hoisting but was actually curious about what you just said Juan. Wasn't sure if the values got hoisted with the declarations.

Comment: @SC_Chupacabra See my comment in that section of the code blahOne, blahTwo, blahThree are all undefined if `something !=== true`

Comment: @ThomasJunk They do not have to be garbage collected, if `something !== true`, the variables will never be assigned a value and there won't be anything to garbage collect, they will be cleared off the stack when the function returns.

Comment: »they will be cleared off the stack when the function returns. –  Juan Mendes « Yes. That is what I actually ment. My description was wrong ;)